# What is the probability $X + Y > 100$? $X,Y \sim U[40,80]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm struggling to write out the integral for this. Both $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d. distributed uniformly over $[40,80]$.

I think it should be of the form $\int_{40}^{80} \int_{100-x}^{80} \frac{1}{40\times40}dy~dx$ but this evaluates to $1$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Suggestion. Draw a picture of the points in the plane that satisfy the condition and find out what fraction of the rectangle it covers. You could do that with an integral but simple geometry is easier.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to these questions is to draw a picture.  (In fact, I'd contend one should always attempt to draw a representative picture for math problems.  The process of thinking about how to draw the picture is helpful to solve the problem.)

We're concerned with the region $x+y > 100$, where $x$ and $y$ are uniformly distributed from $40$ to $80$.  So, [let's plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2By+%3E%3D+100;+x%3E%3D40;+y%3E%3D40;+x%3C%3D80;+y%3C%3D80+for+x+from+0+to+100,+y+from+0+to+100) $x+y=100$ and some bounds for $x=40$, $x=80$, $y=40$, and $y=80$:

[image: Sample plot]

Now, we return to your integral:
\begin{align}
P[x+y \ge 100\; |\; x,y \in A] &= \iint_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) \; dA \\
&= \iint_A f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y) \; dA \quad \text{(because $X$ and $Y$ are iid)} \\
&= \iint_A \frac{1}{40}\cdot\frac{1}{40} \; dA \\
&= \frac{1}{1600} \iint_A \; dA
\end{align}

Now, this raises the question --- how do we compute that integral?  Fortunately, we don't have to!  That integral represents the shaded area in the above graph.  However, even that is kind-of nasty to find.  Thus, we can use our complement rule and realize that the shaded area is just $1-(\text{probability represented by the missing corner})$.

That missing corner is just a triangle of base and height equal to $20$, so its area is $200$ square units.  Let's denote that triangular region by $A^c$ (for $A$'s complement).  Thus: 
\begin{align}
P[x+y \ge 100\; |\; x,y \in A] &= \frac{1}{1600} \iint_A \; dA \\
&= 1 - \left(\frac{1}{1600} \iint_{A^c} \; dA^c \right) \\
&= 1 - \left(\frac{1}{1600} \cdot 200 \right) \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{8} \\
&= \frac{7}{8}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your help, the picture helps clear things up conceptually, but I need to understand how to set up the integral when the distributions aren't uniform, so the picture wouldn't really help. What mistake am I making it setting up my integral?

Comment: @chillz The problem is that your integral doesn't accurately describe the bounds of the trapezoid above --- your bounds describe a big triangle and extends over the bounds of the $[40, 80]\times [40, 80]$ rectangle.  You need to either break this up into multiple integrals, or integrate over only the small triangle, which can be done in a single integral (i.e. do everything the same as in my answer, just don't use the area formula to evaluate the integral)

Comment: They are iid so $X=Y$ (identical as they are iid). $P(X+Y \ge 100)=P(2X \ge 100) $ Where did I do it wrong? What does identical mean here? I asked  this to felix too but i want to know your opinion too.

Comment: @Damandeep Identically *distributed* (don't confuse "identically distributed" with "identical") is not the same as equal --- if you take two fair dice, they are identically distributed (because they both have a 1/6 chance of showing a particular side) and independent (if you roll one, that doesn't impact the other).  However, even with iid, that doesn't mean the dice always show the same number (which would be the case if the random variables they represent were equal).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{40}^{80}{1 \over 40}
\int_{40}^{80}{1 \over 40}\bracks{x + y > 100}
\dd x\,\dd y}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 1600}\int_{40}^{80}\int_{40}^{80}
\bracks{x > 100 - y}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
{1 \over 1600}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\int_{40}^{80}\!\!\braces{\!\!%
\bracks{100 - y < 40}\int_{40}^{80}\dd x + 
\bracks{40 < 100 - y < 80}\int_{100 - y}^{80}\dd x\!\!}\!\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
{1 \over 1600}\braces{%
\int_{40}^{80}\bracks{y > 60}40\,\dd y
+ \int_{40}^{80}
\bracks{y < 60}\pars{y - 20}\,\dd y
}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 40}\int_{60}^{80}\dd y +
{1 \over 1600}\int_{40}^{60}\pars{y - 20}\dd y =
\bbx{7 \over 8} = 0.875
\end{align}

Comment: @RossMillikan I'll ckeck it. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're integrating the Iverson bracket --- I haven't seen this technique before, but it looks cool!  Would it be possible for you to expound just a little more on the rules you employ? (e.g. especially how you negate the integral/adjust the bounds in line 3?)

Comment: @RossMillikan Fixed. I missed one term. Thanks.

Comment: @apnorton You divide in cases: $\left. 1\right) 100 - y < 40,\
\left. 2\right) 40 \leq 100 - y < 80,\ \mbox{and}\ \left. 3\right) 100 - y \geq 80$. Option $\left. 3\right)$ doesn't contribute at all. Iverson bracket allows to handle the whole answer without any drawing which is quite fine but I'm very bad for that.

Comment: Ah! I see it now.  Thanks

Comment: @apnorton You're welcome !!!.

Comment: How do you obtain the fourth equality? Where does the $40$ and $(y-20)$ come from?

Comment: See my comment-reply to $\texttt{@apnorton}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin They are iid so X=Y (identical as they are iid). $P(X+Y \ge 100)=P(2X \ge 100) $ Where did I do it wrong? What does identical mean here?

Answer (score 0):

Comment. I used a simulation in R to make the picture suggested by @EthanBolker.

```
set.seed(1214);  m = 30000
x = runif(m, 40, 80);  y = runif(m, 40, 80)
s = x + y;  cond = (s > 100)
plot(x, y, pch=".")
points(x[cond], y[cond], pch=".", col="green2")
mean(cond)
[1] 0.8707
```

[image]

The distribution over the square is uniform. So it is enough to figure out
what fraction of the square is colored green.

To make a nice picture $m = 30,000$
points is about right. But for a really good approximation to the right answer,
not nearly enough. Even so, your answer ought to be somewhere near 0.87 (as elegantly shown by @apnorton).

Although it is not necessary to do so, it might be good practice to set up the
limits for the double integral over the black region and subtract from $1.$ What is the (constant) value of the joint
density function $f(x,y)$ over the square with vertices at $(40,40)$ and $(80,80)?$ Obviously, that's not *completely* trivial, because we
accumulated one wrong answer on this page (now disappeared) while I was fussing with my simulation (and
answering a couple of telemarketing calls).

Comment: Thanks for your help, the picture helps clear things up conceptually, but I need to understand how to set up the integral when the distributions aren't uniform, so the picture wouldn't really help. What mistake am I making it setting up my integral?

Comment: Maybe the problem was posed to give you the insight that you can sometimes use algebra and geometry instead of double integration. But I'm glad that you are practicing setting up the limits on double intervals. // Easiest to set up a useful integral if you integrate over the black region to get 1/8, then subtract from 1. If you try to integrate over the green region, you can split the integral over $x$ into two parts $(40,60)$ and rectangle $(60,80).$ In almost all cases it _helps_ to have a good picture, even if the picture doesn't automatically give the answer.

Comment: Thank you! that helps a bunch

Comment: @They are iid so $X=Y$ (identical as they are iid). $P(X+Y \ge 100)=P(2X \ge 100) $ Where did I do it wrong? What does identical mean here? I asked this to felix and apnorton too but i want to know your opinion as well.

Comment: "Identical" means having the same distribution, but it does not mean that $X \equiv Y$ or that $X + Y = 2X.$ For example, if $(X,Y)$ has an uncorrelated standard bivariate normal distribution, then $X$ and $Y$ are independently NORM(0,1), so $(X,Y)$ might be a model for target practice where the bull's eye is at $(0,0).$ But having $X\equiv Y$ would mean all shots must concentrate on a 45 degree line through the origin.

Comment: @Damandeep. Another example would be tossing two fair coins. Each has the distribution $P(H) = P(T) = 1/2.$ So each of the outcomes $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ has probability $1/4.$ But it is hard to imagine as realistic the model in which the two coins are totally linked in such a way that only outcomes HH and TT can occur.